# In Git, how do I configure a hook to run a server-side commands after a commit is accepted?

Tags: python, django, git, localization, githooks

I'm trying to figure out my way with the Django localistion stuff and from what i've understood, the `makemessages` command needs to be run every time you change some strings in code. I was thinking of simplifying this process by using a server-side Git hook.

I have no knowledge about Git hooks and couldn't find any resources on the web that did something like this. Is there a reason why one shouldn't have a Git hook to do something like this? If not, could you explain on how I could get the `makemessages` command to be run every time someone commits code to the repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure thing!

Add a script called `post-receive` to the server side git repository in the `.git/hooks/` directory.

Make sure that the file is executable.

Call makemessages from the script.

Done! (I think...)

You'll find some example scripts in the directory already, with most available hooks.

Have a look at [the online Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) if you need more information on Git hooks.